# highcharts changing dial value interactive with mouse events

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, interactive, gauge

Is there a possibility to change the dial value of a gauge chart interactive with e.g. mouse events? If yes, do you have any jsfiddle or other links, which you can share? Unfortunately, I didn't found any useful links, so that I am asking you.

Thank you very much in advance.

Yours sincerely,

Answer (score 0):

I hope I did understand your question correctly :)

Here is a fiddle, where the value is changed:
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/gauge-speedometer/

The most important parts are:

```
            var point = chart.series[0].points[0],
            point.update(newVal);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. This example, I also saw, but I would like to click for example on the dial and drag it to the point of 30km/h. This means that I can interact with the dial.

Comment: There isn't any built-in functionality for such thing. There is [draggable-points](http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/3/Draggable-Points) plugin, but it doesn't support gauge. You need to develop that on your own.

Comment: Hello @PawełFus this is the think I have searched for. I also use the stack column diagramm, this example I can use, thank you :). But do you have any suggestions how I can do the same for a gauge diagram?

Comment: Open source for draggable-points plugin, check how it's made, and to the same for gauge (with improvements of course). I'm pretty sure it will be harder than for simple points, because you need to translate mouse position to radial position in the gauge..